# matplotlib подписи в круговой диаграмме

Tags: python, matplotlib

Нужно сделать круговую диаграмму, и вот ее код:

```
data_names = ["Заработная плата исполнителей", "Cоциальные взносы", 
"Накладные расходы", "Затраты на расходны материалы", "Затраты на электроэнергию"]
data_val = [225920, 67776, 45184, 2700, 840.7]

dpi = 80
fig = plt.figure(dpi = dpi, figsize = (1000 / dpi, 600 / dpi) )
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 11})

plt.title('Распределение статей расходов (%)')

plt.pie(
    data_val, autopct='%.1f', radius = 1.1,
    explode = [0.15] + [0 for _ in range(len(data_names) - 1)] )
plt.legend(
    bbox_to_anchor = (-0.16, 0.45, 0.25, 0.25),
    loc = 'best', labels = data_names )
fig.savefig('pie.png')
```

В результате получилось
[image: Круговая диаграмма]

Как видите,подписи самых маленьких секторов смешались друг с другом. Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас есть настолько тонкие секторы, то врядли у вас получится хорошо отобразить проценты (так чтобы они не смешивались / касались).

Вот, что я имею ввиду - я вынес проценты за пределы пирога:

```
dpi = 80
fig = plt.figure(dpi = dpi, figsize = (1000 / dpi, 600 / dpi) )
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 11})

plt.title('Распределение статей расходов (%)')

plt.pie(
    data_val, autopct='%.1f', pctdistance=1.4, radius=1,
    explode=[0.15] + [0 for _ in range(len(data_names) - 1)] )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте вместо этого отобразить проценты в легенде:

```
total = sum(data_val)
labels = [f"{n} ({v/total:.1%})" for n,v in zip(data_names, data_val)]

dpi = 80
fig = plt.figure(dpi = dpi, figsize = (1000 / dpi, 600 / dpi) )
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 11})

plt.title('Распределение статей расходов (%)')

plt.pie(
    data_val, radius=1.1,
    explode=[0.15] + [0 for _ in range(len(data_names) - 1)] )
plt.legend(
    bbox_to_anchor = (-0.16, 0.45, 0.25, 0.25),
    loc = 'best', labels = labels )
#fig.savefig('pie.png')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]